# AWS Aurora mySQL vs Aurora postgreSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We decided to go with AWS Aurora (and not with RDS-MSQL or RDS-PostgreSQL directly)

Ignoring the SQL syntax differences and the different clients that I will use to connect.
What are the main points to consider?
Mainly on those areas:
DR, BCP, Performance, backups, restores, and maintenance efforts.

The DB will be used to replicate the operational DB to let analytics and reports run on it without impacting the production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is potentially opinion based, but there's lots of good info on the FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/.

In my experience, the native AWS services are more 'first class' services than others, and can require less management/intervention/oversight.

Update: just to add to this based on a slide on some training that I'm working through, Aurora is/has:

- 5x throughput of MySQL on same hardware
- Compatible with MySQL 5.7 so almost drop-in replacement
- Storage is fault tolerant and self healing
- Disk failures are repaired in the background
- Detects crashes and restarts
- No crash recovery or cache rebuild required
- Automatic failover to one of up to 15 read replicas

And also supports additional endpoints for e.g. reporting, read only, etc etc.